# VBScript to take PC's name, remove anything thats not a letter or number (i.e. A-BC-123 -> ABC123)

Tags: vbscript, rename

Me and a non-programmer would appreciate some help with `VBScript` to remove anything that's not a letter or number from the PC's name and store the modified name. Then join or rejoin the domain.

*Example:*

```
pc name: pc-home-543
rename: pchome543
join domain: homeworkplay
restart and it all works
```

Comment: Do you have PC name list in txt file?

Answer (score 1):

You can rename a computer using the [`Rename`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa393056) method of the [`Win32_ComputerSystem`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394102) WMI class. For replacing non-alphanumeric characters use a regular expression.

```
Set net = CreateObject("WScript.Network")
Set wmi = GetObject("winmgmts://./root/cimv2")

Set re = New RegExp
re.Pattern = "[^a-z0-9]*"
re.Global  = True
re.IgnoreCase = True

For Each sys In wmi.ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_ComputerSystem")
  sys.Rename re.Replace(net.ComputerName, "")
Next
```

You need to reboot the computer for the name change to become effective:

```
CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run "shutdown -r -t 0"
```

I don't think you need to re-join the system to the domain afterwards, but if you do, you can do it with the [`JoinDomainOrWorkgroup`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa392154) method of the same WMI class.